# Rescuing redirect :back after destroy in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a best practice solution to be able to keep using redirect :back after a successful destroy action, as many items can be deleted from a variety of listings.

Unfortunately that strategy fails for the one case when the delete is initiated from the item view itself.

What approach do you recommend for this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to consider what behaviour you'd like if an item is deleted from its own view page..

I'd suggest one of two options:

Keeping your `redirect :back`, and implementing some kind of second redirection if the requested resource no longer exists - i.e. `/products/10` redirects to `/products`

```
@product = Product.find_by_id(params[:id]) # although I admit I'm not sure
redirect_to products_path unless @product  # about this
```

Or change the redirect if the particular path matches the destroyed one

```
@product.destroy # you might need to save the path before you destroy the object..
redirect_to :back and return unless request.referrer == product_path(@product)
redirect_to products_path
```

I don't think there's a set-in-stone standard for this kind of scenario, but may I stand corrected.

Comment: I like your 2nd option as it avoids another redirect. Thanks.

Comment: It's referer (not referrer) and I think product_url (instead of product_path).